# Query mongoDB for a date between two dates misses some documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document in a collection name `chats`:

```
{
    "_id" : 25281,
    "conversation" : [ 
        {
            "time" : "1970-01-18T20:16:28.988Z"
        }, 
        {
            "time" : "2018-11-09T18:43:09.297Z"
        }
    ],
}
```

For some reason this specific document is not returning in the below query, although similar documents are returning as expected.

Here is the query:

```
db.getCollection('chats').find({"conversation.1.time": 
    { 
        "$gte": ISODate("2018-11-09T00:00:00.000Z"), 
        "$lt": ISODate("2018-11-10T00:00:00.000Z")
    }  
})
```

Comment: What's the type of `time` in your document ? Is it string or ISODate ?

Comment: @mickl Its a string in the DB. The query is done via roboMongo Console.

Comment: Mongo is typeless Schemeless DB isn't it?

Comment: yes it's schemaless but types matter, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document is not matched because there's a mismatch between `ISODate` specified in your query and `string` in your data model. MongoDB checks types before values so that's why you're getting no values. From [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#type-bracketing)

> For most data types, however, comparison operators only perform comparisons on documents where the BSON type of the target field matches the type of the query operand.

There are three ways to fix that. You can change the type in your query:

```
db.getCollection('chats').find({"conversation.1.time": 
    { 
        "$gte": "2018-11-09T00:00:00.000Z", 
        "$lt": "2018-11-10T00:00:00.000Z"
    }  
})
```

or you need to convert the data in `chats`:

```
{
    "_id" : 25281,
    "conversation" : [ 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("1970-01-18T20:16:28.988Z")
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2018-11-09T18:43:09.297Z")
        }
    ],
}
```

Alternatively you can take a look at [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) operator in Aggregation Framework (introduced in MongoDB 4.0):

```
db.getCollection('chats').aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            value: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$conversation", 1 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                    { $gte: [ { $toDate: "$value.time" }, ISODate("2018-11-09T00:00:00.000Z") ] },
                    { $lt: [ { $toDate: "$value.time" }, ISODate("2018-11-10T00:00:00.000Z") ] },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a query i can do in order to go over all the `time` fields in all `conversation` arrays in all `chats` documents and update them to `ISODate("ORIGINAL_STRING_HERE")`

Comment: You can use $type operator to query such documents (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

Comment: From now and on all of them will always be Date types.
However the current state of the DB is that some are dates and some aren't. That is why i want to fix them all to be dates. If there isn't any query that will know how to convert them all, i'll have to write a script that does