# Cannot use Mongo's Filter with DateTime and BsonString?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using C3 with mongo and I'm trying to query documents by `dateCreated` property.

For example , if I extract the first record by :

```
var models = await c.FindAsync(a=>true);
var list = await models.ToListAsync();
list.First().Dump();
```

Then I see the result :

[image]

Please notice that the value is `BsonString` , and that I have no entity behind it.

The problem is that now  , I want to query the collection based on datetime :

So I did this :

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>
.Filter
.And
(
    Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gte(x => x["dateCreated"].AsBsonDateTime , DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10000)) // old enough
);
 
var models = await c.FindAsync(filter);
var list = await models.ToListAsync();
list.First().Dump();
```

But I get  : *InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements*

**Question:**

How can I query the collection based on datetime knowing that the collection date is stored as BsonString ?

Comment: Have you considered using BsonDocument to build a weakly-typed query and to use $toDate in order to get the date converted on the database side?

Comment: @mickl this `Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gt( "dateCreated" ,  DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-5).ToString("o")) ,` did work. But why must I convert it to string....... ??

Comment: MongoDB is type safe when it comes to queries - if you compare string against DateTime there will always be no result. So your workaround makes sense here, if you want to do it the other way around then $toDate allows you to do the conversion on the database side and pass DateTime as a parameter

Comment: @mickl can u please provide a tiny example how can I mix $toDate  with C# ?

Comment: Something like here (bottom example): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250093/query-mongodb-for-a-date-between-two-dates-misses-some-documents/53250236#53250236 you need BsonDocument type in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921425/c-sharp-mongodb-driver-cant-find-the-way-to-run-complex-query-for-anyin-filter/61925918#61925918